# Can't move focus on LIstView items with custom FocusNodes

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building a dynamic ListView with textfields. Each time the user clicks a button, I add a textfield and the textfield receives focus, and the previous textfield unfocuses. However, a bug occurs where I'm unable to unfocus the textfield by clicking another textfield. Moreover, I can't dismiss the keyboard. If I click another textfield, the focus moves to that textfield for a brief second going back to the original textfield.  No matter where I click on the screen (another textfield or button) I can't move the focus.

```
class myOptions extends StatelessWidget {
    final List<FocusNode> _focusNodes = [];
    int optionCount = 0;

    void addOption () {
        final FocusNode _node = FocusNode();
        setState(() {
            optionCount = optionCount + 1;
            _focusNodes.add(_node);
        });
    }

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ListView.builder(
            shrinkwrap: true,
            primary: false,
            itemCount: optionCount,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return myTextfield(
                    focusNode: _focusNodes[index],
                    shouldFocus: options == (index + 1)
                );
            }
        );
    }
}

class myTextfield extends StatelessWidget {
    final FocusNode focusNode;
    final bool shouldFocus;

    myTextfield({this.focusNode,this.shouldFocus});

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        if (shouldFocus) {
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode);
        }

        return TextField(
            focusNode: focusNode
        ;)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your problem. Replace the `if` condition in your `myTextfield` widget's `build` method to the following.

```
if (shouldFocus) {
   focusNode.requestFocus();
}
```

Also don't forget to dispose the nodes by overriding the `dispose()` method.

```
_focusNodes.forEach((node){
   node.dispose();
});
```

You're calling `setState` on a stateless widget and there are some other issues in your code that you've posted here. I hope this is not what the code looks like in your project. It has to be different. or else it wont run.